# Instalar OCI8 en PHP para XAMPP en OSX Yosemite

Tags: php, oracle

Buenas a todos.

Estoy intentando instalar OCI8 para conexion a una base de datos Oracle en mi XAMMP 5.6.

He seguido la guía que marcan en PHP, instalando el Instant Cliente de Oracle y descargando desde PECL el OCI8 para mi versión.

En resultado sigue siendo el mismo: **Call to undefined function oci_connect().

¿Alguien lo ha instalado en un sistema igual o parecido?

Agradecería algunos comentarios si alguien lo ha conseguido y como lo hizo.

Gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenos días, hace algunas semanas estuve con algo similar, la solución esta en crear las variables de sistema y agregar el path respectivo. Ya que sin ellas el XAMPP no ve el cliente Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Hace unos años tuve que instalar OCI8 en PHP para XAMPP, pero en Debian Squeeze.
Tuve tantos problemas que decidí hacerlo manualmente y no utilizar XAMPP. Te dejo un [post](http://proyectosbeta.blogspot.com/2012/04/instalar-oci8-en-php-en-debian-squeeze.html) que hice en ese entonces, pero es para Debian. Nunca utilice OSX Yosemite, pero te podría ayudar en dar alguna una solución.

Mi recomendación es dejar de usar XAMPP y hacerlo manualmente, o instalar una maquina virtual GNU/Linux y programar desde ahí.